# Azure Policy enforce only for new resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I am creating an Azure policy to enforce some naming conventions. I want to enforce this policy only for any new resources being created.  I am planning to use `Deny` as an `Effect`.

Will the `Deny` effect block the existing resources being re-provisioned?

Is there any way to implement this without impacting the re-provisioning of old resources?  As per the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#deny), it says updating will be prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link that you provided the policy is applied "When creating or updating a matched resource".

However, you can enforce a policy per resource group.

So, if you have the possiblity to have all the existing resources in one resource group and all the new resources in a second resource group. Then you can get around it by applying the policy only to the second resource group.

Comment: How that work at enterprise scale? 100s of subscriptions and 1000s of resorce groups...

Comment: It doesn't, but you did not mention that you had an enterprise scale problem. You have 2 options: 1. implement policy per subscription / resource group. 2. fix the naming of all existing resources before you apply the policy.